# Kotlin infix function shadows/hides member function

Tags: jersey, kotlin, jersey-2.0, kotlin-extension

I am just trying to write some examples with Kotlin. And what I did was to create a Jersey app, and everything was going well until I try to change the `Main.java` class to `Main.kt`.

The generated `Main.java` class has this method;

```
public static HttpServer startServer() {
    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
            .packages("com.kotlinexperiments")
            .register(new AbstractBinder() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    bind(new UserService()).to(IUserService.class);
                }
            });

    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
}
```

And I try to convert it to a Kotlin file;

```
fun startServer(): HttpServer {
    val resourceConfig = ResourceConfig()
            .packages("com.kotlinexperiments")
            .register(object: AbstractBinder() {
                override fun configure() {
                    bind(UserService()).to(IUserService::class)
                }
            })

    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(baseUri), resourceConfig)
}
```

The problem is, when you type in IDE with `bind(someInstance).to(class)` it shows the member function, but when you run/debug it, it is going to infix function which is already defined in `Tuples.kt` file, which is distributed with `kotlin-stdlib`.

The question is, is there a way to call the member function? I try to escape the function name etc. but nothing worked actually.

Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
bind(UserService()).to(IUserService::class)
```

with

```
bind(UserService()).to(IUserService::class.java)
```